# How to enable Github Repository Used By Feature?

Tags: github, npm, package

I published my own package in npmjs.com which is currently kept in my own github repository.
How will i use the feature mentioned in the screenshot so that i know how many people used my package.

I tried searching the code analysis tabs and other settings still not getting a hold of it.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFuFC.jpg)